# How to filter in a component?

Tags: ember.js

I want to filter one of the objects being passed into my component, however, the lack of answers when I Google this suggests I am going about solving this particular problem the wrong way, but it's hard to Google for what you're doing wrong :P

My data model looks like this:

```
App.Browser = DS.Model.extend({
    slug: attr('string'),
    versions: DS.hasMany('version', {async: true})
});

App.Version = DS.Model.extend({
    browser: DS.belongsTo('browser'),
    version: attr('string'),
    status: attr('string')
});
```

I want to create a component (`versions-list`) that, when passed a browser's versions will separate the versions into different groups based on their status (a string that is one of beta, current, or retired).

```
<h1>Beta Versions</h1>
     Version 43.0<br>
     Version 42.0
<h1>Current Version</h1>
     Version 41.0
<h1>Retired Versions</h1>
     Version 40.0
     Version 39.0
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very knowledgeable friend helped me solve this! Our solution:

1) Add computed properties to the version model to signal whether or not the version belongs in a catagory:

```
App.Browser = DS.Model.extend({
    slug: attr('string'),
    versions: DS.hasMany('version', {async: true})
});

App.Version = DS.Model.extend({
    browser: DS.belongsTo('browser'),
    version: attr('string'),
    status: attr('string'),
    isBeta: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'beta'),
    isCurrent: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'current'),
    isRetired: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'retired'),
});
```

2) In the component, check for the existence of the property to determine if it should be printed:

```
<h2>Current Versions:</h2>
{{#each versions as |version|}}
  {{#if version.isCurrent}}
    {{version-details version=version}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

<h2>Beta Versions:</h2>
{{#each versions as |version|}}
  {{#if version.isBeta}}
    {{version-details version=version}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change up the Version model. I'd create a separate property that holds the integer value and another for the string attribute. Depending on how you are able to access the data this code may be different.

```
App.Version = DS.Model.extend({
    browser: DS.belongsTo('browser'),
    version: attr('number'),
    versionString: Ember.computed('version', function() {
      return 'Version' + this.get('version');
    }),
    status: attr('string'),
});
```

Then in your component you can have separate properties that filter the proper version number. For the component definition.

```
{{versions-list model=versions}}
```

In the component itself

```
betaVersions: Ember.computed('model', () => {
   return this.get('model.versions').filterBy('version', (item) => {
      return item > 41; 
   })
}),

currentVersion: Ember.computed('model', () => {
   return this.get('model.versions').filterBy('version', (item) => {
      return item === 41; 
   })
}),

pastVersions: Ember.computed('model', () => {
   return this.get('model.versions').filterBy('version', (item) => {
      return item < 41; 
   })
})
```

And in the template

```
<h1>Beta Versions</h1>
{{betaVersions}}
<h1>Current Version</h1>
{{currentVersion}}
<h1>Retired Versions</h1>
{{retiredVersions}}
```

The idea is to pass the versions to the component and let the component filter the versions as computed properties. Then in the template, access the resulting list.

Comment: Version #41 will not always be the current version. I would have to evaluate version.status to determine what the current version number is, and unfortunately versions can't be evaluated like regular numbers :(

(because 1.9 is a lower version than 1.10 but not a lower number)

I also can't be sure there will be only 1 current version :(

So yeah, no control over the data :/

Comment: Ah yeah that makes it a bit annoying to do, you'd have to do some string manipulation to get it to filter correctly.